# Opening a new browser window via JQuery not sending all values via parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, window.open

Having a issue with windows.open();

- Framework :Asp.netMVC
- Code:C#,Razor
- Issue :jquery

When the function trigger it should send parameters to the controller
`firstname`, `lastname`, `dob`, and `gender` but I am having an issue it just sending `firstname` and other parameters are null. when i debug it on the client side it is showing all parameters have values but when it calls action result it just sending one parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".ViewGet").click(function () {
         var firstname = $(this).closest("tr").find(".firstname").text();
         var lastname = $(this).closest("tr").find(".lastname").text();
         var dob = $(this).closest("tr").find(".dob").text();
         var gender = $(this).closest("tr").find(".gender").text();

         window.open('@Url.Action("FindClientsFor","ClientSerach")?lastname=' + firstname, "&" + +"firstname=" + lastname + "&dob=" + dob + "&gender=" + 1 + 'popUpWindow', 'height=750, width=960, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');

     });
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FindClients(string firstname, string lastname, string dob, int? gender,FormCollection collection)
{
     if (IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) || IsNullOrEmpty(lastname) || IsNullOrEmpty(dob) || gender == null)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     else
     {
         var obj = _repo.ClientSearchWithAll(firstname, lastname, dob, gender);
         //_repo.SortUserNames(obj);
         return View(obj);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `window.open` parameters have major concatenation issues.

You used `+ +` and `firstname, "&"` which breaks the concatenation, and forgot to pass a comma (`,`) before the `window.open` 2nd and 3rd arguments.

You also mixed the `firstname` and the `lastname` variables.

Try this:

```
window.open('@Url.Action("FindClientsFor","ClientSerach")?lastname=' + lastname + '&firstname=' + firstname+ '&dob=' + dob + '&gender=1', 'popUpWindow', 'height=750, width=960, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
```